# Is there a way to ensure scale of records while streaming from kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm new to Spark and Kafka, using pyspark (spark 2.4.8).

Assume we have a kafka streaming source and we want to stream at least `N` records to our database. What is the best way to ensure the wanted number of records and stop after reaching it?

I thought maybe to count the number of micro-batches using a global parameter, and to limit the number of offsets per micro-batch but I guess it isn't the right way to get over the problem.
My code in general:

```
raw_stream_df = spark.readStream \
              .format("kafka") \
              .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_server) \
              .option("subscribe", "topic1, topic2") \
              .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
              .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", offsets_number) \
              .load()
...
# define schema (not relevant)
...

counter = 0
def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
  global counter
  counter += 1

query = streaming_df \
      .writeStream \
      .outputMode("append") \
      .format("memory") \
      .queryName("query1") \
      .foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function) \
      .start()
```

Buy It didn't work. I tried to stop the query after reaching a const number of micro-batches but the counter even didn't increase.

Back to my question, what is the right way to pass the lower bound of requested records and than just stop?

Comment: I'm not sure Spark is really the right tool for this kind of granularity. It's primary intention is to write the entire input source. That being said, have you tried using any other Python Kafka libraries where counting messages isn't going to be distributed across multiple "executors"?

Comment: Can you give an example for "other Python Kafka libraries" that might help me here? I'm really confused.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/3-libraries-you-should-know-to-master-apache-kafka-in-python-c95fdf8700f2